# NodeJS: understanding promise

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am starting to use promise in NodeJS. The requirement is to use these because of async calls. Here is the first code I wrote for promise.

```
function asyncFunc(data) {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            try {
                resolve(data);
            } catch (err) {
                reject("Custom Error");
            }
        });
}
//Usage:
asyncFunc('Sample String')
    .then(result => { console.log(result); })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error); });

//Output:
Sample String
null

//If I change the code to:
function asyncFunc(data) {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            try {
                reject("Custom Error");
            } catch (err) {
                resolve("Data");
            }
        });
}
//Output:
//Exception has occurred: string
//I get the above exception at line: reject("Custom Error");
```

So the question is "reject" can only be used from "catch" block? Why can't I raise "reject" event manually? What is the scenario "reject" is used? Can someone provide me a better example where I can use both "resolve" and "reject"?

Comment: What version of node you use? I just tested your code and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reject if you want, of course.
Let's suppose you have a function that resolves a promise if a person is adult, and rejects it if not.

You'd have something like this:

```
function asyncFunc(age) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(age >= 18) {
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            // here you call reject manually outside of a catch block
            reject(false);
            // or
            // reject(Error('not adult'));
        }
    });
}
```

usage:

```
asyncFunc(19).then(result => {
    console.log(result); // true
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error); // false or Error('not adult')
});
```

Comment: It executes when 19 is passed as parameter. When I pass 17 as: asyncFunc(17).then(result => {
            console.log(result); // true
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error); // false or Error('not adult')
        }); the execution raises an exception: Exception has occurred: boolean at the same line. Although console.log prints "false"

Comment: Are you sure? When I try it on the chrome console it doesn't raise any exception, just returns me 17.

Comment: Moreover. I tried this using node v8.9.4 without any problem

Comment: You mean you didn't get any exception?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you got something like *(node:5009) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.*

Looks like you run your `asyncFunc(..)` in console. In this case node.js first execute your function after your hit `Enter`. Try to take your code to curly brackets like this:

```
{
 asyncFunc('Sample String')
     .then(result => { console.log(result); })
     .catch(error => { console.log(error); });
}
```

Comment: No. I am calling this function from inside of another function. Not using console. This is part of an API.

Comment: Could you please provide yours node.js version?

Answer (score 0):

In case of a `try/catch` block you usually `reject` at `catch` but you can also `reject` in `try`.

`resolve` and `reject` are basically callbacks for Promise. if you `resolve` it will got to the next chain if you `reject` it will break the chain.

So should use reject when an error occurs cause reject will break the promise chain.

For example.

Lets say you have a `function` that works with callback and you want to wrap it in a Promise like function. This `function` will check if user exists in database. If the User is found it will return `true` if not `false` and if there is an error in database (eg connection) it will reject.

```
function checkUserExist(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        checkUserExistInDatabase(id, function(result, error) {

            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }

            if (result != null) {
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                resolve(false);
            }

        })

    });
}

function databaseError() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject();
    })
}

var idsThatExist = [];

checkUserExist(1).then(function(exist) {

    if (exist)
        idsThatExist.push(1);

    return checkUserExist(2)

}).then(function(exist) {

    if (exist)
        idsThatExist.push(2);

    return databaseError(3)

}).then(function(exist) {
    //WILL never Reach here
    if (exist)
        idsThatExist.push(3);

    return checkUserExist(4)

}).then(function(exist) {

    if (exist)
        idsThatExist.push(4);

}).catch(function(err) {

   //it will skip checkUserExist(4)
    console.log('I got rejected after checked users:'
        idsThatExist)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is "reject" can only be used from "catch" block?

No, You can use `reject` anywhere. `Catch` isn't necessary to use `reject`

> Why can't I raise "reject" event manually?

You can reject using creating `new Promise()` or `static` methods of `Promise` . See `promiseUsingNew()` and `promiseUsingStaticMethod()`

> What is the scenario "reject" is used?

`try/catch` is used for error handling in synchronous programming. `resolve` & `reject` is for error handling in asynchronous programming operation instead of callbacks.

> Can someone provide me a better example where I can use both "resolve" and "reject"?

```
'use strict';

function promiseUsingNew(marks) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (marks < 0 || marks > 100) {
      return reject('Invalid marks');
    }

    if (marks >= 40) {
      return resolve('You passed');
    } else {
      return resolve('You Failed');
    }
  });
}

function promiseUsingStaticMethod(marks) {
  if (marks < 0 || marks > 100) {
    return Promise.reject('Invalid marks');
  }

  if (marks >= 40) {
    return Promise.resolve('You passed');
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve('You Failed');
  }
}

// you can use promiseUsingNew(marks) or promiseUsingStaticMethod(marks)
promiseUsingNew(221).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```